# Why are 300+ Huawei bots crawling my forum?

Tags: security, forum

Since a few days ago, I've seen a huge increase in traffic to my forum by guest users, all use the same ip range which traces back to china, Huawei to be more specific.

Is there any indication why this is happening, and from a security perspective, should I preemptively ban the whole IP range?

Comment: **Is there any indication why this is happening, and from a security perspective...** You already indicated that it is bot activity from Huawei, a state company in China often associated with military intelligence, I cannot see what the advantage of allowing the access to continue would be. You want users and not machines with a few exceptions for search engines and the like. If it is unwanted or unless traffic, I would block them quickly regardless of who they are. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc That was my first impression too. Thanks. I needed someone to verify my thoughtprocess. :)

Comment: @Closetnoc please don't use the comments to post answers.  (and welcome back!)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I did not feel I had enough actionable info to form a valid answer, but rather an opinion which anyone could cull from their nether regions... which to me is not necessarily an answer. Thanks for the comment. Cheers!!